# How can i display category title over thumbnail?

Tags: categories, thumbnails

I am trying to implement a slider on my site but i cannot find out how to display the category for each post displayed. I want it to display over the thumbnail. is there a code i can enter to display category?

Comment: A post can have multiple categories assigned to it. Are you working within the WordPress Loop? Perhaps, just a few more details on where you are having troubles would help to answer your question.

Comment: What have you tried already? Show us your code. And welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1):

To get the current category of the post

just try this

```
$cats = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );

echo $cat_name = $cats[0]->name;
```

Comment: @icanhazgiraffe please accept this answer. If you said this solution worked for you, mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_post_category($postId) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (!is_null($postId)) {
        $conditions = "AND p.id=" . $postId;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    $conditions .= " AND ttax.taxonomy='category'";
    $selectfields = "term.name name";
    $query = "SELECT " . $selectfields . "
                    FROM   wp_posts p 
                    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships trel ON trel.object_id = p.id 
                    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ttax ON ttax.term_taxonomy_id = trel.term_taxonomy_id 
                    INNER JOIN  wp_terms term ON term.term_id = ttax.term_id  
                    WHERE 1=1 " . $conditions ." LIMIT 1";
    return $wpdb->get_results($query);
}
```

This function needs the post id as parameter and it will give you the top most category of the post, if you remove LIMIT, it will give you a list of all categories of the post. I am not sure whether you want achieve the same or not.

Comment: not sure you really need to drop down to SQL for this - what's wrong with using `get_the_category()` or similar?